# ASP.NET Identity multiple profiles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

This is an ASP.NET MVC 5 application using Identity and EF.

EDIT

Entities:

ADMIN: Web site administrators. All of them would have an admin role and other roles depending on the resources they can access iwithin the administration panel.

USERS: Common users. The could access to their private panel to edit their profiles and access some services.

TEAMS: Work teams. A work team consist in a group of users and one user can be in many different work teams.

Scenario:

I'd like to have 3 different login pages: administration panel, one for the common users and another one for the work teams.

1. How can I have 3 different login pages since Identity allows you to set just one?
2. I'm thinking to have a user as the admin of each work team. That user can get into the work team private zone, but how can I do that?
   Also, that user can give rights to other users in the work team to get into the work team zone.

So on the work team private zone I have to controll not only the user logged but also the work team id to show its data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are "Companies" and how user accounts relate to the companies?

Comment: I have changed the question to be more clear. Thanks.